# Cambiar color de botones PHP según DataTable

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola buenos dias quisiera ver si me pueden apoyar con lo siguiente:

tengo un mapa elaborado con botones con estilo en css 
y lo que quiero hacer es que cambie de color segun el codigo del datatable, es decir si el data table dice codigo COM y la bahia es CMPA debe cambia el boton CMPA a color azul.

Comment: Debes poner el código y lo que has intentado

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, ademas deberias agregar tu codigo.  Sin codigo es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Con puro PHP no lo vas a lograr, necesitas usar minimamente JavaScript o JQuery, con AJAX, para hacer la consulta y ahí hacer la evaluación para cambiar la clase del botón con los métodos `removeClass()` y `addClass()` de JQuery.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.